# when i open Visual Studio Code it shows this message 'Disk Connection is Unavailable'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code But i have some problem, the error message is:

The drive or network connection that the shortcut 'Visual Studio Code.Ink' refers to is unavailable.
Make sure that the disk is properly inserted or the network resource is available

Comment: It looks like that the .lnk does not point to the proper place. Can you tell us where VSCode was installed, and where the .lnk points?

Comment: yes, i solved that issue. firstly i installed VSCode in D drive and then for some reasons i delete my drive D without uninstall the VSCode. After that i install new VSCode in C drive, so that why this error is shown.

Comment: I restore files from recycle bin and unistall old VsCode. then error was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an invalid shortcut pointed to a file on an unlinked drive and didn't find the answer here. But sometime later found another solution eventially for all such broken shortcuts. I'll leave it here and may be it help to someone else.

To reproduce, you can subst the drive, create the shortcut file with the path on that drive and unsubst the drive:

1. Run `cmd.exe`
2. `subst b: <existing-file-on-connected-drive>`
3. Create shortcut file on connected drive but with target path `b:\...`
4. `subst /d b:`
5. Open the shortcut

The shortcut is broken but the actual path is still exist.

There is a service which does resolve such links (Windows 8.1):

> Service Name: TrkWks
>
> Display Name: Distributed Link Tracking Client
>
> Description: Maintains links between NTFS files within a computer or across computers in a network

Run it and it will try to fix the shortcut on the open.